# Getting "MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: *" when trying to bulk query in salesforce

Tags: sql, simple-salesforce

I'm trying to work around Salesforce's limit of 2000 documents per query and found a solution:

```
# simple_salesforce set up as sf

query = "SELECT * FROM Opportunity LIMIT 10"
fetch_results = sf.bulk.Opportunity.query(query, lazy_operation=True)

all_results = []
for list_results in fetch_results:
    all_results.extend(list_results)
```

For which I get the error message `simple_salesforce.exceptions.SalesforceGeneralError: Error Code Failed. Response content: InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: *`

What's weird is that I'm getting a normal response when not using `*` e.g. when `query = "SELECT * FROM Opportunity LIMIT 10"`.

I need all fields in my query - does anyone know how to select all fields? I've tried googling the issue but seeing as `*` is a google functional characted and I've not found a way to escape it in a search this has been very difficult. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct syntax in case anyone else had this problem: `FIELDS(ALL)` is the correct substitute for `*` so we have `query = "SELECT FIELDS(ALL) FROM Opportunity LIMIT 10"`